# Can't use QWERTY layout after make IBus work with Dvorak layout after reboot

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-layout, input-languages, dvorak

To keep my Input Method (Bogo or Unikey) of IBus working with Dvorak keyboard layout after reboot, I use sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration to set keyboard as Dvorak, and go to tab Advance in IBus Preferences to check Use system keyboard layout.

The problem is, sometimes my friends want to borrow my laptop and I can not easily switch to Qwerty layout because any Input Method will use Dvorak. The English - English (US) is the same as English - English (Dvorak) one.

Any idea? Please help. Thank you very much.

Info: I'm use IBus 1.5.3 and it says this is the newest version. So do Cinnamon.